# How does the "User has role" visibility rule work in Panels?

Tags: panels

I'm using Panels and I have added a "User has role" visibility rule to a pane.

I want to show the pane only if the user does not have Role A or Role B.

I configured the rule as follows:

- User: **Logged in user**
- Roles: **Role A**, **Role B**
- I then  checked **Reverse (NOT)**

However, this doesn't work.  I tested with a user who does not have Role A or Role B, but the pane still appears.  Even if I only check **Role A** and not **Role B**, the pane still appears.

How can I configure a pane to show only if a user does not have either of two roles?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but could it be that setting both roles gives you an OR, while you expect an AND? Could you try adding two rules, one for each role?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck all criteria must pass and check only one criteria must path

you will find it clicking  settings under add new rule tab

Comment: Isn't that the opposite of what the OP is asking?